# Is there the full Wolfram Language in Mathematica?

Tags: core-language

Today I read the [new entry on WolframBlog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/03/25/injecting-computation-everywhere-a-sxsw-update/) with all it's nice little demos.
I was realy interested in those with astronomic informations, but trying these with my own Mathematica I was irritated:

Steven Wolfram wrote in the blog: "... You can use the Wolfram Language completely interactively, using the notebook interface we built for Mathematica."

So I typed, like he did:

```
In: Sunrise[]
Out: Sunrise[]
```

So I didn't get the result in the blog. Same with other demos from the blog.

So my question is:
How can I use Wolfram Language with Mathematica? And how can I get it?

(Yes I know, with indirections (WeatherData) I could do it with Mathematica too, but I wanted to do it like in the blog's demos.)

Comment: He is showing features that are not yet released, but will probably be part of the next version (soon?)

Comment: So far, many of the functions in the demo are not even in the 10.0 on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Online preliminary documentation contains a [`Sunset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sunset.html?q=Sunset) entry with the footnote: "Introduced in 2014 (10.0)" which I think is a strong indication that it will be included in _Mathematica_ 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wolfram Language has not yet been released, so we can't say for sure. However it seems likely that the next release of Mathematica will include the new commands that you saw in Wolfram's demo. The alternative would be for Mathematica's language to diverge from the Wolfram Language, which seems like pointless complexity for Wolfram to manage, and such divergence would probably reduce the user base for a language they seem eager to promote.

Comment: The real question is: would _Mathematica_ 10 contain ALL functions of the Wolfram Language or some can only be used from under other software platforms? _SystemModeler_ has many functions not included in _Mathematica_, but whether those are considered as part of the canonical WL... who knows at this point?

Comment: @IstvánZachar [This](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7441017) is interesting to read (click "parent" for context).

Comment: @Szabolcs Interesting to see that "the local IDE for the Wolfram Language" and _Mathematica_ are not going to be the same thing! I guess this IDE (perhaps a new Workbench version?) is one of the two [coming soon](http://www.wolframcloud.com/) platforms.

Comment: So which will be the platform with full function coverage? Wolfram IDE (with Wolfram Laguage) > Wolfram Mathematica? Will there even be one product with full coverage, or do "we" have to buy all products to have full function coverage?