# Distinguishing Wolfram Language and Mathematica, the software

Tags: core-language

Which features are part of *Mathematica*, the software, and which features are *Wolfram Language*?

I would say there has to be a line discriminating the two somewhere. One could say that *Mathematica*, in addition to implementing WL, also includes:

- Libraries beyond standard libraries one has to explicitly `Get` (eg. `Notation`).
- [Wolfram Knowlagebase](https://www.wolfram.com/knowledgebase/) with real data.
- Notebook specific features, which actually require a front-end to evaluate.

Why do I ask? I am writing a thesis, and I was wondering if I should say

> *Wolfram Language* command `Flatten` and `Partition`.

or

> *Wolfram Mathematica* function `DepthFirstScan`.

If I would implement my own kernel, I would consider it a must to implement `Table`, `Flatten`... but I do not think an implementation of a language requires implementation of `DepthFirstScan` with a narrow application.

I find these related:

- [Is Mathematica an Implementation of the Wolfram Language?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37557/is-mathematica-an-implementation-of-the-wolfram-language)
- [Is there an open source implementation of Mathematica-the-language?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4454/is-there-an-open-source-implementation-of-mathematica-the-language)
- [Is there the full Wolfram Language in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44860/is-there-the-full-wolfram-language-in-mathematica)

I have also browsed [Notes for Programming Language Experts](https://www.wolfram.com/language/for-experts/) which was not specific.
The [Fast introduction for programmers: Built-in Functions](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/built-in-functions/) claims

> With 5,000 carefully integrated, built-in functions delivering
>   computation and knowledge

which sounds a bit like everything implemented in MMA is WL.

[Language Overview guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LanguageOverview.html) has an overview of all(?) syntax features, which perhaps are well on the language side of the discrimination. I also [discovered `WolframLanguageData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframLanguageData.html), which might share some light into the matter.

Comment: I would claim (but with some reservations) that things that are primarily front-end operations should perhaps not be seen as WL kernel functions. On the other hand this means that things like exporting any `Graphics` to an image are not part of the language as they make use of the FE through `Rasterize`. So it’s certainly a bit of a slippery thing to get a handle on. Still, the fact that a different front-end may be attached to a kernel makes me suggest that.

Comment: Do you want to consider figure rendering capability as a language specification?

Comment: Here's one answer: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Mathematica-and-Wolfram-Language

Comment: Look through the videos [on Twitch](https://www.twitch.tv/stephen_wolfram/videos/all) with names that end with "in #WolfLang" and you will see that the things you consider not to be part of the language are all considered part of the language by Stephen Wolfram and at Wolfram Research in general. Wolfram Language is a high-level language that is meant to be able to express ideas tersely and easily. Even functions such as `ImageIdentify` are part of the language and help realize S.W.'s vision for the language.

Comment: If you start taking away functions then you will immediately decrease the number of ideas that can be easily expressed. This is the opposite of where this language is heading. This language is going to get many, many more functions so that it can express even more ideas in a short and easy manner, and those functions will all be part of the language. Personally, this is one of my favorite aspects of Wolfram Language. Who knows what problems Wolfram Language speakers will be able to solve in ten years.

Comment: Thanks for great comments! I think they should be answers I start to agree with. A good answer IMHO not only states a fact, but gives all this explanation as well.

Comment: I agree that answers should explain themselves, and the question is well posed for a longer answer as well. We have had discussions before in the chat room about whether there is a "core language" that would make sense on its own, but no one seems to know exactly what that should be. If I were to write an answer I would like to put some more time into it, but I don't have time right now.

Answer (score 8):

Simple answer - Mathematica is a platform for working with the Wolfram Language, analogous to Visual C and the C language. In that sense, Mathematica is the front end. You don't have to use Mathematica to write and execute Wolfram Language programs; they can be submitted to the kernel as text files. I believe this simple answer is essentially  correct.

Comment: I think you are sidestepping the question. Is `DepthFirstScan` a language primitive (as `for` in C) or is it written in the language and part of a standard library (as `printf` is part of `stdio.h`)?

Comment: I think this is the right answer. Mathematica is a frontend.

Comment: You might find the answers to this similar question helpful.  bit.ly/2pdA3Qo

Comment: I prefer real links, which also show the target. The referred question: [Is everything in Mathematica ultimately stored as a rule?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34530/is-everything-in-mathematica-ultimately-stored-as-a-rule). This also makes the questions show up on the right side menue of both questions.